# Automapper returning "default" instance of mapped entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm trying to get automapper working for .NET core, and I seem to be missing something important.

I have my automapper set up as follows:

In `Startup.cs` in my `ConfigureServices` method, I have the following line:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup), typeof(ApplicationDbContext));
```

I also have a class called `MappingProfile` which resembles this:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CfGroup, GroupModel>()
            .IgnoreAllUnmapped();
        CreateMap<GroupModel, CfGroup>()
            .IgnoreAllUnmapped();
        ...
    }
}
```

The `IgnoreAllUnmapped` was suggested by another SO question, and it looks like this:

```
    public static IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> IgnoreAllUnmapped<TSource, TDest>(
        this IMappingExpression<TSource, TDest> expression)
    {
        expression.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Ignore());
        return expression;
    }
```

My CfGroup looks like this:

```
[Table("Groups")]
public class CfGroup
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    [StringLength(250)]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int FounderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FounderId")]
    public virtual CfUser Founder { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreatedTimestampUtc { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3000)]
    public string About { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<UserGroupMember> Members { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<UserGroupManager> Managers { get; set; }
}
```

... and my GroupModel looks like this:

```
public class GroupModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public string About { get; set; }
}
```

When calling my web api endpoint, I get a collection of `CfGroup` entities from the database just fine.  I then run a command like so:

```
var dtos = entities.Select(_mapper.Map<GroupModel>);
```

...but my dtos are "empty"... IOW, the instance is created, but `Id` value is set to 0 and all the string values are set to `null`.  That is definitely not what is in the `entities` variable.

I have also tried to explicitly convert it like so:

```
var dtos = entities.Select(x => _mapper.Map<GroupModel>(x));
```

and, postulating that it's an `IEnumerable` issue, tried making a `List` out of it:

```
var dtos = entities.Select(x => _mapper.Map<GroupModel>(x)).ToList();
```

...but no matter what, the DTO's remain instantiated, but with all properties set to their default values.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think `IgnoreAllUnmapped` extension method is what you want. You basically said ingore mapping for all members. Try without it?

Comment: Hmm... it looks like you're right.  However, if I don't have that, my `ConfigurationProvider.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` test fails with unmapped properties... which is what the `IgnoreAllUnmapped` was supposed to address... sigh

Comment: That extension method does work only if you remap them again manually (after you call `.IgnoreAllUnmapped()`, which is quite a lot of work.

Comment: So it would appear.  So, I can do this the easy way and drop the validation test, or the hard way... not a difficult choice.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah if you want to do validation test, there is one way to solve this, configure your mapping with `MemberList.None` or `MemberList.Source` can't remember which on top of my head. So it would be `CreateMap<CfGroup, GroupModel>(MemberList.None)` or the other one. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation for more info.

Comment: I'll look into it, I appreciate the assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the `IgnoreAllUnmapped` was not the correct way to go; in fact, the mapping seemed to work fine without it.  I took out the extra "exception handling" code and it worked as I wanted it to.  I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it may be because you are mapping inside your linq expression. try something like this:

```
var dtos = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<GroupModel>>(entities.ToList());
```

Comment: You are correct.  No one should ever map before all the entities have returns unless you use the `ProjectTo()` AutoMapper method.